# editGridRow does nothing

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm trying to setup jqGrid to add a row to the table, but editGridRow() isn't doing anything.  The grid is displayed and populated with the sample data, and the 'Add Record' button fires an event (the alert fires), but then, nothing.

Perhaps my grid specification is missing something b/c I'm populating it with stub data via addRowData()?  I'm baffled here.

UPDATE: editGridRow depends on the CSS stylesheets, which weren't included in my HTML.

HTML:

```
<table id="myGridTarget"><tr><td/></tr><table>
<div id="pager"/>
<fieldset>
  <input id="addRowButton" type="button" value="Add Row Data"/>
</fieldset>
```

Code setting up the grid and events:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {        
jQuery("#myGridTarget").jqGrid(pageData.gridData);
var starter_data_obj = {
                         'Col_1': 'first',
                         'Col_2': 'second',
                         'Col_3': 'third',
                         'Col_4': 'fourth',
                       };

jQuery("#myGridTarget").addRowData('row_1', starter_data_obj, 0);

jQuery("#addRowButton").click(function () {
    alert("here");
    jQuery("#myGridTarget").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit:false});
        }
    );
    }
);
```

Specs for the grid, placed in the object pageData.gridData. (Please note, these are python values, and jasonified before passage to griData.  So True becomes true, object properties aren't in quotes, etc.)

```
{
     'url': '',
     'datatype': 'json',
     'mtype': 'GET',
     'loadonce': True,
     'jsonReader': { 'repeatitems': False },        # potential js object issue
     'colNames': 
        [
         'Col_1',
         'Col_2',
         'Col_3',
         'Col_4',
        ],
     'colModel':
        [
         { 
           'name': 'Col_1', 
           'key': True,
           'width': 60,
           'align': "center",
           'hidden': False,
           'editable': True,
         },
         { 
           'name': 'Col_2',
           'width': 80,
           'sortable': False,
           'hidden': False, 
           'editable': True,
         },
         { 
           'name': 'Col_3',
           'width': 180,
           'sortable': False,
           'hidden': False, 
           'editable': True,
         },
         { 
           'name': 'Col_4',
           'width': 180,
           'sortable': False,
           'hidden': False,
           'editable': True,
         },
        ],
     'rowNum': 10,
     'rowList': [10, 20, 300],
     'pager': "#pager",
     'viewrecords': True,
     'gridview': True,
     'rownumbers': True,
     'height': 230,
     'caption': 'Caption goes here',
     'editurl': '',
     'sortorder': 'desc',
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editGridRow() functionality depends on the jqGrid CSS stylesheet.

Once I incorporated the CSS stylesheet into my HTML, the dialog box for additional data popped right up.

Comment: Is the problem solved and the grid do all what needed correct now?

Comment: _This_ problem is solved.  I would have marked this closed but stackoverflow won't let the original poster do so for two days.  Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should fix the problem with `True` and `False` values. Is the data which you posted are not the data used in `pageData.gridData` it make more difficult to find the problem. It would be better if you included the real definition of the `pageData.gridData`.

In the `pageData.gridData` one can find no `url`, but the `datatype: 'json'`. You can not do this.

Next and probably very important problem is `loadonce:true` parameter. It change the `datatype` from `'json'` to `'local'` after the first load. The form editing and the function `editGridRow` **not support working with local data**. So probably you will have problem with `editGridRow` and to make it working you will have to switch `datatype` to `'json'` before usage of `editGridRow`. Then if you will use `reloadAfterSubmit:true` the grid will be reloaded and the `datatype` will be cahnged to `'json'`. I don't play with such settings combination, so you have to make some experiments yourself or examine the source code of [grid.formedit.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js).